# MySpace oauthentication login using php

Tags: oauth, myspace

I have tried searching the internet for this, but couldn't find. Is there any documentation for authentication procedure from PHP web application for MySpace login. Can anyone give me example URL where from i can download source code to connect with MySpace account?

Answer (score 0):

implement the cURL extension in the PHP script, works wonders... Lately Myspace has been running sweeps to clear out accounts that use any form of automation for logging into accounts and automating actions on the site... I wrote a function to grab the input variables for the form to create the post data..